# Issues with highchart responsive when pointwidth set for column chart

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-highcharts

Is it possible to make column chart responsive when viewed on small screen?
i have set pointwidth to 120 property in plotOptions when i view it in small screen like mobile or tablet column bars gets one over other. Is there way to render chart view so that for small size screen it can viewed properly?

```
export  class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  @ViewChild('container') chartContainer: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this);
    this.createBarChart();

  }

createBarChart() {
  // Create the chart
  Highcharts.chart('bar-container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',

    },
    title: {
      text: null
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
          style: {
              color: '#c5c5c5',
              fill: '#c5c5c5',
          },
     },

     title: {
         text: null
     }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {

          },
          column: {
              /* Here is the setting to limit the maximum column width. */
              pointWidth: 120,
              // maxPointWidth: 60,
              stacking: 'normal',

          },

  },

    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<b>{point.y:f} hours</b>',
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        style: {
          color: '#fff'
        }

    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
  },

    'series': [
        {
            'name': 'Hours Per Period',
             color: {
              linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
              stops: [
                  [0, '#05e06f'],
                  [1, '#00b1f5']
              ]
             },
            'data': [
                {
                    'name': 'Week 1',
                    'y': 65,
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Week 2',
                    'y': 45,
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Week 3',
                    'y': 37,
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Week 4',
                    'y': 80,
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Week 5',
                    'y': 95,
                }
            ]
        },
    ],


    //     responsive {

    // },

  });
}
}
```

some spaces between column bar is required.. any solution
using angular 5, highcharts 5

Answer (score 0):

You can use `responsive` property to add conditions and define specific chart options:

```
responsive: {
    rules: [{
        condition: {
            maxWidth: 500
        },
        chartOptions: {
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointWidth: 20,
                    stacking: 'normal'
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mr5qL2de/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive

Comment: Tried using this but it throws an error:

Argument of type '{ chart: { type: string; renderTo: string; zoomType: string; reflow: true; }; title: { text: null; }; xAxis: { type: string; labels: { style: { color: string; fill: string; fontSize: string; fontWeight: string; }; }; title: { ...; }; }; ... 6 more ...; responsive: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'responsive' does not exist in type 'Options'. [2345]

Comment: Hi user5788012, This error looks very strange. Could you reproduce this situation in some online code editor, like: https://codesandbox.io/s/543l0p0qq4 ?